# flutter textfield labeltext not showing up

Tags: flutter, dart

I cant get the textfield labeltext to show. anyone can help? and how do I get the border to always showing and not disappear when I click on the text field.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: new BorderSide(width: 1)
        ),
        // hintText: _hintText,
        labelText: "Label Text",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
        // suffixText: _nameLength.toString() + "/ " + _maxLength.toString(),
        // suffixStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        // suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.color),
        // counterText: "",
      ),
      maxLines: _maxLines,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      cursorRadius: Radius.circular(10),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: true,
      maxLength: _showTextCount ? _maxLength : null,
      style: TextStyle(color: AppSetting.textColor1),
      validator: (val) {
        // if (val.isEmpty) {
        //   return 'Please enter text.';
        // } 
        // return null;
      },
      onChanged: (val) {
        _onChanged(val);
        setState(() {
          _inputFieldText = val;
          _nameLength = _inputFieldText.length;
        });
      },
      onTap: () => AppSetting.hapticFeeback(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```dart
                                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                                          width: 2.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: primaryColor,
                                          width: 2.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          width: 2.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the default value of `labelColor` of the input decoration is different from background (the default label color was white in my case). In order to show border when clicked set `focusedBorder` property.